# Add individual observations on ggplot (geom_line)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame  [data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb5kd.jpg) and I am plotting the average (Accuracy) per level. But I want to also the individual data points with shapes (e.g.Accuracy1, Accuracy2, Accuracy3 etc) on the line. Anyone who could help me? Thanks

```
ggplot(data=Accuracy_means, aes(x=Effort_Level, y=Accuracy, 
                                group=1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Accuracy-se, ymax=Accuracy+se), width=.05, size=1) +
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(-0.5,0.5), linetype="dashed", colour="black", size=0.5)+
  ylim(0,1)+
  coord_fixed(ratio = 2.5)+
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Please, can you provide the output of `dput(your_data)` instead of an image of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you want to change the line type. If so, here is an approach using `gather` from `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

Accuracy_means %>% 
  gather(key = accuracy_vars, value = values, -Effort_Level, -Accuracy, -se) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Effort_Level,
             y=values)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Accuracy-se, ymax=Accuracy+se), colour = "red", width =0.05, size = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = accuracy_vars), size=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Accuracy), colour = "red")+
  coord_fixed(ratio = 2.5)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]